# I need to get the sum of next 5 rows that are order by one specific column

Tags: sql, sqlite

actual table

```
YEAR  TOT
----  ---
2001    1
2002    2
2003    3
2010   10
2011   11
2012   12
2013   13
2014   14
2015   15
```

Now Expected Results :

```
YEAR  TOT  Exp_res
----  ---  -------------------
2001    1  1+2+3+4+5      = 15
2002    2  2+3+4+5+6      = 20
2003    3  3+4+5+6+7      = 25
2010   10  10+11+12+13+14
2011   11  11+12+13+14+15 
2012   12  12+13+14+15 
2013   13  13+14+15 
2014   14  14+15 
2015   15  15
```

Comment: Is the data incomplete?  The expected results have the values 4, 5, 6, and 7 that do not appear in the original data.

Comment: Looks like a bad denormalized design to me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do what you want with a correlated subquery, using a `limit` clause:

```
select id, tot,
       (select sum(tot)
        from t t2
        where t2.id >= id
        order by t2.id
        limit 5
       ) as Exp_Res
from t;
```

Comment: Exp_Res whole column coming same number like 10290082 not 5 row sum